# Disable modal shown on navigation back press using javascript in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, maven, jsp

I am new to jsp and creating one jsp page. In which we are showing modal in page A at the time page loading. Till this time it is working fine. But when I go to page B and press back to come page A it again shows the modal. It is supposed to not show again on back press.

I am sharing my code of page A below

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="author" content="colorlib.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

<![endif]-->

<!--Bootstrap-->

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.center-block {
    float: none
}
</style>

<title>Forum</title>


</head>



<body>

    <div class="s01">
        <form action="shops.jsp" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Search Powered By Forum</legend>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="inner-form">
                <div class="input-field first-wrap">

                    <select id="search" name="someName"
                        onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this)"
                        style="font-size: 25px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">

                        <option value="">-- Select Sector --</option>

                    </select>
                    <div id="div1"></div>
                    <br>

                </div>
                <div class="input-field second-wrap">

                    <select name="shopType" id="location"
                        onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this)"
                        style="font-size: 25px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
                        <option value="All">All</option>

                    </select>
                    <div id="div2"></div>
                    <br>

                </div>
                <div class="input-field third-wrap">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-search" type="button"
                        onclick="return Validate()">Search</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>



    <!--begin modal window-->

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">

                    <div class="pull-left">Forum</div>

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        title="Close">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>

                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <!--CAROUSEL CODE GOES HERE-->

                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">

                        <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="https://smartchs.co.in/forum_images/KF_Page1.jpeg"
                                    alt="item0">

                                <div class="carousel-caption"></div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="https://smartchs.co.in/forum_images/KF_Page2.jpeg"
                                    alt="item1">

                                <div class="carousel-caption"></div>

                            </div>



                            <!--end carousel-inner-->
                        </div>

                        <!--Begin Previous and Next buttons-->

                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button"
                            data-slide="prev"> <span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a
                            class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button"
                            data-slide="next"> <span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

                        <!--end carousel-->
                    </div>

                    <!--end modal-body-->
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <small>Powered By Mauli Infotech (OPC) Pvt. Ltd.</small>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn-sm close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <!--end modal-footer-->
                </div>

                <!--end modal-content-->
            </div>

            <!--end modal-dialoge-->
        </div>

        <!--end myModal-->
    </div>

    <!--end col-->
    </div>

    <!--end row-->
    </div>

    <ul class="list-inline">



        <!--end of thumbnails-->

    </ul>

    <!--end container-->
    </div>

    <!--latest jQuery-->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--Bootstrap-->

    <script
        src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
</body>


<!-- This templates was made by Colorlib (https://colorlib.com) -->
</html>
```

I have also tried following javascript but not worked

```html
$(window).load(function(){
  
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('homePageAlreadyVisited')  == null)//The first time this will be null
    {
      sessionStorage.setItem('homePageAlreadyVisited', 'foobar'); //foobar can be anything. You are just concerned about checking whether 'homePageAlreadyVisited' key has some value or not.
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
//now coming back to the homepage after navigating to some other pages will not execute anything as this time, if statement is false.
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your provided script works .. Can you check what values are store in sessionStorage onces page get loads? Also, as written [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) if you open new tab with the same URL it creates sessionStorage for each tab/window and onces you close tab the session gets expires

Comment: @Swati Yes it works, but the issue is with when I press back button from other jsp page to page A, the modal reappears. I don't want that on page back.

Comment: check if `sessionStorage`  has any value or not when you load page for first time and when back button is pressed . If you are using chrome do ctrl + shift + i -> go to application tab-> session Storage and see what values are store there .